# Saving Google map snapshots with a custom name

Tags: android, image, google-maps, filenames, snapshot

I am developing an android app that captures images of a Google map (V2). I require the user to name those pictures. The user should be able to name the picture after he presses the snapshot button. Should i put an edit text  into an alert dialog and then put the string from the edit text as the image name? Here is the code I use for capturing those images:

```
public void CaptureMapScreen() {
    SnapshotReadyCallback callback = new SnapshotReadyCallback() {
        Bitmap bitmap;

        @Override
        public void onSnapshotReady(Bitmap snapshot) {
            bitmap = snapshot;
            try {
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)+File.separator+"Rute"+File.separator
                    + "MyMapScreen" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png");

                // above "/mnt ..... png" => is a storage path (where image will be stored) + name of image you can customize as per your Requirement
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 90, out);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    map.snapshot(callback);
}
```

Comment: You can create Dialog inside onSnapshotReady. Inside this dialog, the user will be asked to enter the image name then when he press ok, you will continue in your business.

Comment: Thank you I solved the problem :) I will upload the solution later if somebody else needs it.